# Stopped Nginx still allows root index.html access

Tags: nginx, server

I'm brand new to Nginx. But after running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```

and got

```
Stopping nginx:               [OK]
```

I can still browser index.html from outside ip.

How can I really/completely **stop** Nginx server? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `sudo lsof -i -P | grep 80` give you?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
```

will do the trick

Comment: This is what I actually did, not really stopped the index page access.